# Why doesn't pandas.sum() work across both axes when using axis=None parameter?

Tags: python, pandas, sum

Could anyone explain why pandas doesn't sum across both axes with parameter axis=None. As it said in API reference:

> #### pandas.DataFrame.sum
>
> **DataFrame.sum(axis=None, skipna=True, numeric_only=False, min_count=0, **kwargs)**
> This is equivalent to the method **numpy.sum**
> **Parameters: *axis*: {index (0), columns (1)}**
> Axis for the function to be applied on. For Series this parameter is unused and defaults to 0.
> For DataFrames, specifying **axis=None** will apply the aggregation across both axes.

But when I use parameter axis=None it works the same as axis=0

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,2,3], 'b':[4,6,8]})
df
```

```
Output:
    a   b
0   1   4
1   2   6
2   3   8
```

```
df.sum(axis=None)
```

```
Output:
a     6
b    18
dtype: int64
```

**The same as:**

```
df.sum(axis=0)
```

```
Output:
a     6
b    18
dtype: int64
```

**Shouldn't it work as numpy.sum() works?**

```
import numpy as np
df.to_numpy().sum()
```

```
Output:
24
```

Comment: need pandas version 2.0.0+ https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html

Comment: @Panda Kim  Pandas 2 still gives the same as for axis = 0 although docs suggest otherwise as you indicate

Answer (score 3):

When such malfunction appears one possible solution is to *read the code*. Lets investigate [source code](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/37ea63d540fd27274cad6585082c91b1283f963d/pandas/core/generic.py), `pandas.DataFrame.sum` code is

```
def sum(
    self,
    axis: Axis | None = None,
    skipna: bool_t = True,
    numeric_only: bool_t = False,
    min_count: int = 0,
    **kwargs,
):
    return NDFrame.sum(self, axis, skipna, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs)
```

which prompts inquiry of `NDFrame.sum` actually is

```
def sum(
    self,
    axis: Axis | None = None,
    skipna: bool_t = True,
    numeric_only: bool_t = False,
    min_count: int = 0,
    **kwargs,
):
    return self._min_count_stat_function(
        "sum", nanops.nansum, axis, skipna, numeric_only, min_count, **kwargs
    )
```

which prompts inquiry of what `_min_count_stat_function` is

```
@final
def _min_count_stat_function(
    self,
    name: str,
    func,
    axis: Axis | None = None,
    skipna: bool_t = True,
    numeric_only: bool_t = False,
    min_count: int = 0,
    **kwargs,
):
    if name == "sum":
        nv.validate_sum((), kwargs)
    elif name == "prod":
        nv.validate_prod((), kwargs)
    else:
        nv.validate_stat_func((), kwargs, fname=name)

    validate_bool_kwarg(skipna, "skipna", none_allowed=False)

    if axis is None:
        axis = self._stat_axis_number

    return self._reduce(
        func,
        name=name,
        axis=axis,
        skipna=skipna,
        numeric_only=numeric_only,
        min_count=min_count,
    )
```

Observe `if` taking care of `axis` being `None`, which does set axis value to `_stat_axis_number`, which itself is set earlier to zero

```
_stat_axis_number = 0
```

and is never changed in any other place of available source-code (it seems to be treated as read-only), therefore giving `None` as axis value is same as giving `0`.

Documentation is not compliant with what code is actually doing.

Answer (score 0):

The axis=None parameter in the pandas.sum() function does not work across both axes when there are non-numeric values present in the DataFrame or Series. It only works for numeric data.